# Company name issue on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

I have submitted my app and it is accepted from a company profile. But on app store it is showing an owner name instead of company name? Can anyone please define what is the main reason of this thing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Seller Name Guidelines**

First it is necessary to understand the guidelines for a seller name on the App Store. Your options for seller name depend on which kind of Apple developer account you initially setup. You can either create an account as an individual or a company/organization. As an individual the only option is your legal name. As a company or organization you are required to use your legal entity name. In order to register as a company/organization a D-U-N-S number is required which ensures your company or organization is legally registered.
If you wish to change your seller name, you must operate within those restrictions. Apple hasn’t always enforced these guidelines, but as the App Store has matured these policies have become required. Also, it doesn’t seem possible to convert an Apple developer account registered as an individual to an account registered as company/organization. If that is something you need, you should try App Transfer which is explained below.

**Contact Apple**

The easiest way to change your seller name is to contact Apple developer support. If there is a typo or inaccuracy in your seller name they should be willing to change it. Back before I released Card Share my individual account had a seller name for a fictitious entity that did not exist. Since it wasn’t my legal name, Apple support was willing to make the name change. I contacted support and within 24 hours my seller name was changed and updated in the App Store. The results from this method may vary, but I highly recommend direct communication with Apple as a first approach.
Here is the email to contact Apple about seller name changes and other iTunes related support:

itunesconnect@apple.com

Taken from: http://www.brynbodayle.com/changing-app-store-seller-name/

Comment: No I don't want to change the name, I just wanted to know that why on app store it is showing owners name while team name is *** Inc.

Answer (score 1):

Only one option for you to contact Apple Support.

Submit your request on below link:

https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/

Answer (score 0):

If you registered as a Company, you should see the Company Name on the App Store.

The only way to change that is by contacting Apple Support.

Comment: Yes the Account is registered as a company, but I am not able to see the name of company on app store

Comment: Can you please give me the email address or any source so I can directly contact them?

Comment: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=contactUs